# R: Efficient Way to Relabel Simulation Numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working on a project in R for stratifying the results of some simulations that I have run. Currently the data that I have is stored in a data frame titled "Events", which looks something like this:

```
Events = data.frame(Realization = c(875,875,2150,3675,25), 
                    Event_ID = c(1500,1510,700,810,520), 
                    Loss = c(100,200,250,100,600))
```

and this data goes on for a very long time (~3M rows). What I need help with is finding an efficient function which could allow me to relabel the realization numbers starting at 1. The result should be something that looks like this:

```
Desired_Result = data.frame(Realization = c(875,875,2150,3675,25), 
                            Event_ID = c(1500,1510,700,810,520), 
                            Loss = c(100,200,250,100,600), 
                            New_Realization = c(1,1,2,3,4))
```

I have already tried looping through the data frame row by row but due to the size this is not a feasible solution. It is important that the data frame remain in the same order before and after the operation. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, if 875 occurs again in the column it would still be 1?

I would try this:

```
Events$New_Realization = cumsum(!duplicated(Events$Realization))
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly. Simple and fast! The realizations in the data frame are already sorted so there is no chance of seeing repeat realization numbers further down the rows.

Comment: You are welcome! Have fun crunching the 3M row data.frame =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `factor()` to help here

```
transform(Events, New_Realization = as.numeric(factor(Realization, levels=unique(Realization))))
```